# How to build a static Qt library -- Mac Osx 10.9 XCode 5.1.1 Qt 5.3

Tags: macos, qt, static

I downloaded Qt 5.3 and tried to create static Qt libraries on Mac Osx Mavericks 10.9 with XCode 5.1.1.

like root, I built Makefile with this command:

./configure -static

I tried to run "make sub-scr" but does not work so I executed "make" without any parameter and i got this error:

```
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [audiodecoder.app/Contents/MacOS/audiodecoder] Error 1
make[3]: *** [sub-audiodecoder-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-multimedia-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-examples-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtmultimedia-make_first] Error 2
```

**Somebody know the right procedure to build static Qt library over Mac Osx 10.9 using Qt 5.3?**